# "Email address or key ID cannot be matched to a valid, not expired OpenPGP key" in Enigmail after moving to a new computer/account

Tags: macos, thunderbird, pgp, osx-el-capitan, enigmail

When I write a new email in Thunderbird while signing the mail using Enigmail, I get an error message:

> **Enigmail Alert**
>
> Encrypt draft messages on saving
>
> The email address or key ID 'john@hotmail.com' cannot be matched to a valid, not expired OpenPGP key.
> Please ensure that you have a valid OpenPGP key, and that your account settings point to that key.

This account has an OpenPGP private and public key. Recently I started over with a clean account, and had to recreate the Thunderbird profile. I imported the private keys to sign outgoing emails, which works.

Output for `gpg -K`, for one account. I have several keys, and all keys have this problem.

```
$ pgp -K
sec   4096R/XXXXXXXX 2013-11-09 [expires: 2018-10-11]
uid                  john@hotmail.com
ssb   4096R/YYYYYYYY 2013-11-09
```

For some reason saving mail doesn't work. I have no idea why.

**Why can't Thunderbird save my signed emails? How can I fix this?**

Comment: If you run `gpg -K`, is your OpenPGP key listed?

Comment: Yes - see my updated answer.

Comment: I just remembered Enigmail is using GnuPG 2, which is usually installed as `gpg2`. Would you try again `gpg2 -K`? Also verify there is no broken setup in your _account's preferences_, where you can pin a given OpenPGP key.

Comment: `gpg2` gives the same output. You mean the Thunderbird Account setting "OpenPGP Security"? That is all set to use the email address to identify the key. If I set the key, then it doesn't work either.

Comment: Last two things I can imagine: did you export and import the secret key (while migrating to the new machine), or did you copy the whole folder? If you imported it, you might have to set ultimate trust for the key (`gpg --edit-key [key-id]`, `trust`, `save`). Otherwise, sometimes `gpg-agent` gets stuck. `killall gpg-agent` might help in this case.

Comment: Thanks! It was a trust issue. If you want the points, make it an answer.

Comment: Seems worth putting those debug steps together in an answer, I guess this is an issue to more people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be a set of different problems that occur.

### Private key not imported

If you did not migrate the private keys to the new machine, obviously they cannot be used. `gpg --export` only exports *public* keys, not private ones. Run `gpg --export-secret-keys` in addition.

You can verify whether this is an issue by running `gpg --list-secret-keys` (or the abbreviated version `gpg -K`). Your key should be listed here.

After importing, also see the "trust" section of this answer.

### GnuPG 2.1 does not find the keys

GnuPG 1 and 2 use `secring.gpg` for storing private keys, GnuPG 2.1 moved them to `pubring.gpg`. If you already installed GnuPG 2.1, make sure it also sees your private key. GnuPG 2 is usually installed as `gpg2`: `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`.

If `gpg` lists the keys, but `gpg2` does not, export them from GnuPG 1 and import to GnuPG 2.1:

```
gpg --export-secret-keys | gpg2 --import
```

After importing, also see the "trust" section of this answer.

### Wrong key defined in the account's Enigmail configuration

You might have defined a fixed key in your account's Enigmail configuration. Open the account preferences, and choose "OpenPGP Security" for the respective account. Is there any fixed key configured?

### Missing trust configuration

Enigmail by default only uses verified keys. For being able to verify keys, there must be a *trust path* from a valid key to that key.

Your own key is the *trust source* in the web of trust concept, and should have *ultimate trust*. On the command line, trust can be configured by running `gpg --edit-key [key-id]`. Now, in the GnuPG edit key command prompt, run trust`. The assistant will ask you what trust to provide, choose "ultimate". Finally,`save` the changes.

This can also be done using several graphical frontends for GnuPG, but there are too many to describe how to do this. Have a look whether you find some "trust" settings while editing your own key.